Compatibility Issue with Power BI Service AND R 3.4.4 for some packages (example of ggplot2)
I’m facing a frustrating issue related to using R 3.4.4 on Microsoft Power BI Service. As you may know, Power BI enforces this specific version of R, which severely limits compatibility with more recent R packages.
Current Situation:
R Version: 3.4.4
Environment: Power BI Services
Problem: Cannot install ggplot2 and its dependencies
Key Challenges:
Manual installation attempts fail
Dependency packages are not compatible
Version constraints prevent package updates
Specific Questions:
Has anyone successfully installed ggplot2 on R 3.4.4 recently?
Are there workarounds for package installations in this environment?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers!

I can't help with the question but have you considered Deneb and Vega as an alternative to ggplot. Vega is grammar of graphics and the Deneb container is more integrated with PowerBI offering things like cross filtering etc.

PowerBI is one of the few things I rate as even worse a choice than Excel
